# Windows Shell extention: context menu when more than 16 files are selected

Tags: c#, c++, windows, shell

As I can see, when more than 16 files are selected DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0); returns 16.
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758093%28VS.85%29.aspx
"In Windows 7 and later, the number of items passed to a verb is limited to 16 when a shortcut menu is queried. The verb is then re-created and re-initialized with the full selection when that verb is invoked."

But my FileContextMenuExt::Initialize function is called only once, even if I select more than 16 files. (I checked it out using output to text file).

How can I get full list of selected files and its number?

My question is similar to [Shell Extension: DragQueryFile returns at most 16 (in Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363911/shell-extension-dragqueryfile-returns-at-most-16-in-windows-7?rq=1)
but no solution were found there.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Once you select your action, then initialize is invoked a second time, but this time with the full list? Or am I reading the documentation incorrectly?

Comment: "But my FileContextMenuExt::Initialize function is called only once, even if I select more than 16 files. (I checked it out using output to text file)."

Comment: It's only re-initialized when the verb is invoked.

Comment: You mean when I invoke verb, before verb will actually act, shell should call my Initialize function again with the full list? But in fact, my Initialize function is called only once (Initialize function writes log info with number of files that windows shell gives to it and it's always less or equal to 16).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logic is really quite simple in this case. When you right-click up to 16 items will be sent to the `IShellExt::Initialize` method, followed by the `IContextMenu::QueryContextMenu`

In the case that your verb is invoked (i.e. the `IContextMenu::Invoke` is called) there are two possible paths:

Up to and including 16 items in the selection -> `IContextMenu::Invoke` is called directly.

More than 16 items in the selection then the `IShellExt::Initialize` method is invoked a second time with **all** the items of the selection, followed by `IContextMenu::Invoke`.

If you never invoke the menu item, then you will never get the second call to `IShellExt::Initialize` with the full list of items.

I've a [sample project on github](https://github.com/petesh/SimpleWindowsShellExtension/tree/master) that creates a simple context menu (using C++), which demonstrates the behavior using the truly low-level `OutputDebugString`.